# Original Proof of Riesz Representation Theorem for $C([0,1])^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, duality-theorems, riesz-representation-theorem

It is well known that [Riesz Representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) states that every positive linear functional $\Psi$ on $C_c(X),$ where $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, can be realize as integration 
$$\Psi(f)=\int_X f(x)d\mu(x)$$
for a unique regular Borel measure $\mu$ on $X.$

> Question: In the Wiki article linked above, there is this sentence:
>   **The theorem is named for Frigyes Riesz (1909) who introduced it for continuous functions on the unit interval.**

I would like to know that how Riesz proved the statement himself. It would be good if someone can provide me a paper where he provided a proof.

Comment: try: http://nonagon.org/ExLibris/riesz-proves-riesz-representation-theorem
there are also pdf links in the website to the original paper (in French)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand French. Do you have link to his Eglish translated paper?

Comment: the website is in english, with a description of the proof, also in english. i meant that the original paper (also included as a link in the website) is in french. sorry for the poor wording

Comment: The original of proof of Riesz is not straightforward. There is a straightforward one using the Hahn-Banach Theorem.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts: May I get the proof using Hahn-Banach theorem?

Comment: Extend the functional $\Psi$ to $\tilde{\Psi}$ on $L^{\infty}[a,b]$. Let $\rho(t)=\tilde{\Psi}(\chi_{[a,t]})$ and argue using Riemann-Stieltjes sums that $\Psi(f)=\int_{a}^{b}f(t)d\rho(t)$ for any continuous function $f$. It doesn't take much to show that $\rho$ is of bounded variation.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts: I think it would be good if you can provide a link to your full proof.

Comment: @Idonknow : I know there is one in Bachman and Narici *Functional Analysis*. That's where I first saw it.